# How to display select conditionally using states?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following form item.

```
//データフィールド名項目
$form['media_field_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => '対象項目',
    '#options' => _load_media_mapping_array($media->media_id),
    '#default_value' => isset($edit->options['media_field_id']) ? $edit->options['media_field_id'] : '',    // bugfix: #65997 somukawa chg
    '#description' => '分割条件の判定を行うフィールドを指定してください。',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#disabled' => $disable_mode,
    '#states' => array(
// Only show this field when the 'toggle_me' checkbox is enabled.
'visible' => array(
  ':input[name="export_type"]' => array('value' => 'md5x16'),
    ),
),
);
```

I want to display it only when users select *md5x8* and *md5x16* from the following form item.

```
//出力オプション
$form['export_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => '出力オプション',
    '#options' => _export_type_options(),
    '#default_value' => isset($edit->export_type) ? $edit->export_type : '',
    '#description' => '',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#disabled' => $disable_mode,
);
```

I checked [this documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7.x), but it is not working.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding below statement:

```
'#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="export_type"]' => array(
                array('value' => 'md5x8'),
                array('value' => 'md5x16'),
        ),
        ),
    ),
```